# Error when I try to paste Excel range into Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, paste

I am using the below code to copy a range of cells from Excel to Word.
I have an instance of Word open (blank document). When I run the code, nothing happens. This used to work fine but now the code doesn't do anything. Any idea what is going on?

```
Sub CopyALLtoWord()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1pager").Cells(3, 3)

        Worksheets("1pager").Range("n5").Value = i

        Range("N5").Select
        Calculate

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1pager").Range("L12:AL82").Select
        Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

        'Select Word & paste


        Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        objWord.Selection.Paste

        objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tested the code w/o any issues on Office 365.